# How to handle {STAThread] in C# 9 Using Top-Level Program.cs

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I am just getting into C# 9 and am trying to implement top-level statements, in particular in the ubiquitous Program.cs. I did this successfully in one case, but in the second case the application gets a ThreadStateException in OpenFileDialog().

I replaced the generated Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MapLines {
    static class Program {
        /// <summary>
        ///  The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }
}
```

with

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MapLines;

Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

This is the exception in OpenFileDialog

```
System.Threading.ThreadStateException
  HResult=0x80131520
  Message=Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Forms.FileDialog.RunDialog(IntPtr hWndOwner)
   at System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at System.Windows.Forms.CommonDialog.ShowDialog()
   at MapLines.MainForm.OnOpenImageClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\evans\Documents\Visual Studio 2019\Projects\Map Lines\Map Lines\MainForm.cs:line 664
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, WM msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Going back to the original Program.cs, which has [STAThread], fixes it.

None of the articles on the new features of C# 9 that I have found mention this. It seems important since there must be a lot of applications that use OpenFileDialog() and presumably others. It is my understanding Winforms needs Single Threaded Apartment (STA) threading.  Is there a way to use top-level statements when STA threading is needed?

Comment: No, traditional style required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cs
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MapLines;

var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
    Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
});
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
thread.Start();
```

Comment: Not sure why this currently has a down vote. It seems reasonable and appears to work. Let me try it a while to see if anything breaks (or if anyone has a better idea), and I will mark it as the solution. Whether it is better to use this solution or the generated original version from the template might be debatable, but it answers my question.

Comment: I thought for a long time and haven't found anything better at the moment (maybe something appears in C# 9.1+ that solves this problem). Another possible improvement is the NuGet package, which simplifies this code to calling Main.Run(() => {your-code}).

Comment: I've been using this method and it seems to just work.  I don't see anything all that different from a practical perspective.  I upvoted this.

Comment: Yup this works... from the perspective of "wow look C# 9 is awesome and doesn't need all that boiler plate just to get started!" this is a bit of a let down though from the maintainers. It's great for anything that doesn't require ````STAThread```` but otherwise this isn't fantastic.

Comment: I'd use a `thread.Join()` after `thread.Start()` to wait until the Thread has finished execution.

Comment: `thread.Join()` will actually block the main thread, which is free to exit after `thread` has been started. A C# process won't normally exit until all non-background theads have stopped. As such I guess `thread.Start()` is actually the way to go.

Answer (score 11):

It's possible, this is the minimal example that seems to run well:

```csharp
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// It is unfortunate but we have to set it to Unknown first.
Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.Unknown);
Thread.CurrentThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(defaultValue: false);
Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.PerMonitorV2);

Application.Run(new Form());
```

Source: this ticket from dotnet/winforms Github: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/5071